# How can i show data with semicolon delimited in a column into multiple rows?

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.1

I have a table like below.

```
Id      NAME
---     ------
1        A;B;C
2        D;E
```

I want get the data as below

```
Id      Name
---     -----
1       A
1       B
1       C
2       D
2       E
```

Can any one help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

I think your table is like this

```
    id          |   NAME
----------------+----------
    1           |    A;B;C;
    2           |    D;E
```

then you want to modify like below as

```
    id          |   Name
----------------+----------
    1           |    A
    1           |    B
    1           |    C
    2           |    D
    2           |    E
```

Try this below query

```
select i.id,s.NAME from tablename i, unnest(string_to_array(i.NAME, ';')) s(Name);
```